# VSCODE не видит заголовочные файлы C

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include

Vscode ругается на любые подключаемые библиотеки. Проблема возникает со всеми новыми файлами расширения `.c`. Есть проект, в котором проблемы с подключением библиотек нет.
Перечитал массу информации на данном ресурсе, включая статью по настройке `compilerPath & includePath`, но не помогло.
Код был тестовый, просто что-бы проверить, что все компилится и работает.

Я пытался сравнивать `.json` файлы рабочего проекта и нерабочего, но зависимостей не нашел. Тем более, что в рабочем проекте есть файлы `launc.json & tasks.json`, но не `c_cpp_properties.json`.

Ручная сборка через терминал проходит без каких-либо проблем. Если собирать через vscode, то несмотря на ошибки все равно проект собирается и запускается.
Проблема только в том, что vscode постоянно ругается на заголовочный файл.

Тестовый код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Содержимое файла `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++98",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.makefile-tools",
            "compilerArgs": []
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Ошибки:

```
#include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/run/media/clipslemon/6E4035D04035A02F/Programming/C/sdl_app/test.c).

cannot open source file "stdio.h"
```

Comment: ¿И что, инклюды действительно находятся в папке `/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/include`?

Comment: Дополнение:
Обнаружил, что мои заголовчные файлы хранятся в `/usr/include/`. Однако это не решило проблему.

Comment: @user7860670, там какие-то были, какие-то нет. Но полный список стандартных находится в комментарии выше, но как и сказал, проблему исправить не помогло, все еще не видит, ошибки те же.

Comment: Имхо, стандартный microsoft intellisense - от лукавого. Лучше Clangd. Он работает из коробки без настройки для простых проектов, а для сложных - настраивается генерацией `compile_commands.json`, который все нормальные системы сборки умеют делать сами.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, могу согласиться. Я сколько им не пользовался, от проекта к проекту какие-то шутки у него. Попробую Clangd. Позже отпишусь.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, помогло. Отключил intellisense, установил Clangd и проблема ушла. Кстати, если выключаю Clangd и обратно включаю intellusense, то проблема также пропадает. 
Я бы хотел отметить твой комментарий как решение. Ты можешь его написать в качестве ответа, для отметки?

Comment: Можете сами написать. *"и обратно включаю intellusense"*, Хмм, может он сам отключается, когда видит конфликтующее расширение?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Intellisense странно себя ведет, периодически все равно перестает видеть библиотеки и приходится отключать и включать его.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что они оба одновременно не нужны? Они делают одно и то же. (Ну, разве что майкрософтовское еще отлаживать позволяет, но если это нужно, тогда все остальное - часть, которая делает code completion - нужно отключить.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, я понимаю это, спасибо. Да и сам Intellisense ругается, что запущен Clangd, использую один из них, по ситуации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в расширении C/C++ IntelliSense от Microsoft. Включение и выключение как и его переустановка не помогали, но после установки Clangd проблема ушла. Intellisense не может работать параллельно с Clangd, но теперь при перезагрузке расширения Intellisense все работает должным образом.